# How to change Angular Latest version to old version?

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, version

I have installed angular cli latest version. but I need to update it to cli 7 version

I have try this:

1. `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
2. `npm cache clean npm install -g`

- `angular-cli@7.0.0`

Does anyone know another way to do this please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.10
ng --version
// should hopefully see version 7.3.10
```

7.3.10 is the latest stable version of 7 [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli?activeTab=versions).